# How do I know id thread of interface window?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, hook

There are third-party process with the gui, in which multiple threads running. Need to set the keyboard hook to thread gui this process. I do as follows:

```
processID = 8888; //pid 
 HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
 DWORD threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &processID);
 hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)&KeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), threadID);
```

`processId` insert manually from the Task Manager (for debugging, then he will return to the script). If i replace `threadID` option on the last line to 0, the hook works, but works everywhere - even in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your question? The only real question you are asking is: *"Why does this API behave as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx)?"*

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) it is not possible to target only one thread with WH_KEYBOARD_LL:

> "The scope of a hook depends on the hook type. Some hooks can be set
>   only with global scope; others can also be set for only a specific
>   thread, as shown in the following table."
>
> ...
>
> WH_KEYBOARD_LL    Global only
>
> ...

Note: also one cannot pass current .exe proceess instance that arrives from GetModuleHandle(NULL) to as third parameter to SetWindowsHookEx (DLL handle or NULL is expected here).

Comment: For a low-level keyboard hook you do not need to compile or use a DLL. This pointed out in the documentation: *"This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop."*

Comment: So, how one can filter to accept only those intercepted that arrive from third-party process?

Comment: With a low-level mouse hook you can't. That hook is called **before** the receiver has been determined (that's also the reason why you cannot install it for a specific thread).

Comment: Thanks, so actually one has to use WH_GETMESSAGE to intercept messages that arrave to specific thread/window

Comment: Also interesting thing is that MSDN says "All global hook functions must be in libraries" but WH_KEYBOARD_LL is a global hook, so still DLL is needed. Also, unfortunately MSDN says nothing about thread where GetMsgProc is executed https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644981(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you for all what prompted the idea

Comment: *"so actually one has to use WH_GETMESSAGE to intercept messages that arrave to specific thread/window"* - no, not at all. A regular [keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984.aspx) can be installed for a single thread.

Answer (score -2):

In my task I was required to do so that set hook and KeyboardProc has been located in single area (.cpp file). I found the answer:

1) Made global varible `processID`

2) In set hook method

```
processID = GetCurrentProcessId();
  hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)&KeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
```

3) In KeyboardProc method:

```
DWORD actProcess;
 HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
 GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &actProcess);
 if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
 {
  if (processID == actProcess)
  {
    //do something
  } 
 }
```

Comment: written to at least minus what?

Comment: You cannot use a **low-level** keyboard hook for a specific thread. Your purposed answer is a kludge, that is probably the result of this thought process: *"Oh wow, **low level**! That's so me."* Anyway, it doesn't address the question, and your question is probably not even asking about your **real** issue.